# NextJS: 404 page when Express endpoint returns 404?

Tags: next.js

and API endpoint (Express) sends 404 .
`return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Not Found !!!' })`

In the `_app` Component

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    try {
      const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {}

      const statusCode = ctx.res && ctx.res.statusCode

      return {
        pageProps,
        statusCode
      }
     } catch (err) {
       // What to do here?
     }
```

The app component calls `getInitialProps` in another Component... here is calls the API which will return a 404 status.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
   try {
      const response = await axios.get(route.API_POST(id))
      // do something with response
    } catch (err) {
      //???????
    }
}
```

Only, it does not. It returns `200`.

How do you render a 404 page in NextJS when the Express endpoint returns a 404 status?

Answer (score 1):

In the custom server you are doing:

```
app.render(req, res, page, params)
```

If you modify the `res` object in express changing the `statusCode` to 404, in the route component in NextJS you will have the `res` object and the `statusCode` property. If `res.statusCode` is never 404, try to override it in `getInitialProps`

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    try {
      const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
        ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        : {}

      const statusCode = ctx.res && ctx.res.statusCode

     ctx.res.statusCode = 404

      return {
        pageProps,
        statusCode
      }
     } catch (err) {
       // What to do here?
       // Here you cannot do anything because 
       // you don’t have any throw in the previous statements
     }
}
```

I have noticed that the code above is about the `getInitialProps` of `_app.js`, i don’t know if this works in this component. However, try to add a route and do:

```
static getInitialProps({ res }) {
  if (res) {
    res.statusCode = 404
  }

  return {}
}
```